# Which Perl bindings for selenium webdriver?

Tags: perl, binding, selenium

I am new to selenium 2.0 and working on automation through perl and java(maven-eclipse). I want to know the perl bindings for Se differ.

Selenium website shows https://metacpan.org/module/Selenium::Remote::Driver

While CPAN also has WWW:Selenium bundle....

Which to use to perl automation in this context?

Answer (score 2):

Selenium::Remote::Driver is the one you want. WWW:Selenium is old.

Comment: More specifically, WWW::Selenium doesn't use WebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit the following URL:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/client-drivers/selenium-perl-client-driver/

Comment: You can download "selenium-perl-client-driver-1.0.1.zip" from there which would be helpful, I think